# Ionic cordova plugin ble central, how to wait for Android 9/10 pairing request to be resolved before writing characteristics?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've a BLE peripheral which has a service id and characteristic id for service change, on Android 8 during pairing the android device does not request for pairing and everything works fine, I am able to read all the details and write date to the BLE device. However, my Android 10 device requests for pairing permission and I am not able to wait for the request to resolve before I could write to the device. The service change start notification never returns anything. Am I missing something or is there something going on with the plugin?